# Limit point of A if and only if there exists a sequence converging to it

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following definition of a limit point:

$ x \in \mathbb{R} $ is a limit point of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists a \in A : 0 < |a - x| < \epsilon$

I want to prove that $x$ is a limit point of A if and only if there exists a sequence in A whose limit is $x$ and none of the terms are equal to $x$.

I can prove it one way assuming the existence of a sequence but I'm having some trouble proving the existence of the required sequence by supposing that $x$ is a limit point.

How do I construct a sequence from a single $a$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon = \frac1n$where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. As $x$ is a limit point, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exist an $a_n \in A-\{x\}$ such that $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon$. And this sequence $a_n$  converges to $x$.

Comment: Thanks, that highlighted the main concept of the proof, I just refined my argument a bit.